# Letter descender issue on Contact page

Tags: bug, design, fonts, contact

There is a letter descender issue in the Meta Stack Exchange [Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)'s, list of options in the "What can we help you with?" dropdown list under the "Contact Support".

Screenshot for reference: (Issue with "g", "q", "y")

> [image: letter descender issue]

> [image: letter descender issue]

| Configuration | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 10 Pro |
| Mozilla Firefox | 89.0 (64-bit) |
| Google Chrome | 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) |

Comment: No repro on chrome on android.

Comment: It might be something with these dropdowns in general - descenders are also clipped in the dropdown of revisions that you see when suggesting an edit ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flm23.png))